# Подключение OpenCV к QT

Tags: c++, qt, dll, opencv, lib

Столкнулся с такой проблемой как подключение OpenCV в QT. То работает, то нет, сейчас вообще нет. Как правильно надо подключить все файлы библиотеки.

Содержание pro файла.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-04-24T20:39:23
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = smile_detector
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \


HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h \


FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui \

LIBS += -LC:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin
#LIBS += C:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_world340d.dll
#LIBS += C:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_ffmpeg340_64.dll

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world340
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world340d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/include
```

Если подключить .lib на прямую. То приложение собирается, но при запуске крашится. Если подключать dll, то они не читаются. В какой-то момент у меня получилось все запустить, но сейчас же опять проблемы. Когда я подключаю уже готовый билд от opencv, который шел в комплекте, то все работает. Но мне нужен билд, который я скачал из интернета, и он идут сразу с CUDA.

UPD1: Поменял на win64 в про файле, но теперь выбивает кучу ошибок LNK2019, но так не должно быть.

pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-04-24T20:39:23
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = smile_detector
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \


HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h \


FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui \

#LIBS += -LC:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin
#LIBS += C:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_world340d.dll
#LIBS += C:\opencv\release_2018\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_ffmpeg340_64.dll

win64:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world340
else:win64:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world340d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../opencv/release_2018/include
```

Консоль сборки

```
07:05:13: Выполняются этапы для проекта smile_detector...
07:05:13: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
07:05:13: Запускается: «C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\bin\uic.exe ..\smile_detector\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\smile_detector.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\smile_detector -I. -I..\..\..\..\opencv\release_2018\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtPrintSupport -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.7288.15.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\smile_detector.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\smile_detector -I. -I..\..\..\..\opencv\release_2018\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtPrintSupport -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\qcustomplot.obj.7288.15.jom
    cl -BxC:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -E ..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >debug\moc_predefs.h
qcustomplot.cpp
main.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\smile_detector.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\smile_detector -I. -I..\..\..\..\opencv\release_2018\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtPrintSupport -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.7288.31.jom
mainwindow.cpp
    C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include debug/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc -IC:/Qt/qt_projects/smile_detector/smile_detector -IC:/opencv/release_2018/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtPrintSupport -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtCore -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" ..\smile_detector\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
    C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include debug/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc -IC:/Qt/qt_projects/smile_detector/smile_detector -IC:/opencv/release_2018/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtPrintSupport -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/include/QtCore -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" ..\smile_detector\qcustomplot.h -o debug\moc_qcustomplot.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\smile_detector.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\smile_detector -I. -I..\..\..\..\opencv\release_2018\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtPrintSupport -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.7288.3109.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
..\smile_detector\mainwindow.cpp(99): warning C4267: аргумент: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
..\smile_detector\mainwindow.cpp(124): warning C4267: аргумент: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
..\smile_detector\mainwindow.cpp(135): warning C4189: h: локальная переменная инициализирована, но не использована
..\smile_detector\mainwindow.cpp(392): warning C4267: =: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
..\smile_detector\mainwindow.cpp(360): warning C4189: rect_height: локальная переменная инициализирована, но не использована
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\smile_detector.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\smile_detector -I. -I..\..\..\..\opencv\release_2018\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtPrintSupport -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -I\include -I..\..\..\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_qcustomplot.obj.7288.4875.jom
moc_qcustomplot.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\smile_detector.exe @C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\smile_detector.exe.7288.12687.jom
main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "private: void __cdecl cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AEAAXXZ) в функции "public: __cdecl cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QEAA@XZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""private: void __cdecl cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AEAAXXZ)"
moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""private: void __cdecl cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AEAAXXZ)"
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPEAX@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "private: char * __cdecl cv::String::allocate(unsigned __int64)" (?allocate@String@cv@@AEAAPEAD_K@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl cv::String::String(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0String@cv@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::error(int,class cv::String const &,char const *,char const *,int)" (?error@cv@@YAXHAEBVString@1@PEBD1H@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::Mat::operator=(class cv::Mat &&)" (??4Mat@cv@@QEAAAEAV01@$$QEAV01@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Rect_<int> const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QEAA@AEBV01@AEBV?$Rect_@H@1@@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::Mat::operator()(class cv::Rect_<int> const &)const " (??RMat@cv@@QEBA?AV01@AEBV?$Rect_@H@1@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ) в функции "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@QEAAXAEBV12@@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class cv::cuda::Stream & __cdecl cv::cuda::Stream::Null(void)" (?Null@Stream@cuda@cv@@SAAEAV123@XZ) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount(void)" (?getCudaEnabledDeviceCount@cuda@cv@@YAHXZ) в функции "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl cv::cuda::getDevice(void)" (?getDevice@cuda@cv@@YAHXZ) в функции "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(int)" (?printShortCudaDeviceInfo@cuda@cv@@YAXH@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::resize(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,class cv::Size_<int>,double,double,int)" (?resize@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@AEBV_OutputArray@31@V?$Size_@H@1@NNH@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::equalizeHist(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &)" (?equalizeHist@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@AEBV_OutputArray@31@@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::cvtColor(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,int,int)" (?cvtColor@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@AEBV_OutputArray@31@HH@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::rectangle(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputOutputArray const &,class cv::Point_<int>,class cv::Point_<int>,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &,int,int,int)" (?rectangle@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputOutputArray@debug_build_guard@1@V?$Point_@H@1@1AEBV?$Scalar_@N@1@HHH@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::circle(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputOutputArray const &,class cv::Point_<int>,int,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &,int,int,int)" (?circle@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputOutputArray@debug_build_guard@1@V?$Point_@H@1@HAEBV?$Scalar_@N@1@HHH@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::putText(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputOutputArray const &,class cv::String const &,class cv::Point_<int>,int,double,class cv::Scalar_<double>,int,int,bool)" (?putText@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputOutputArray@debug_build_guard@1@AEBVString@1@V?$Point_@H@1@HNV?$Scalar_@N@1@HH_N@Z) в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ cvInitFont в функции "public: class cv::Mat __cdecl MainWindow::detectAndDraw_image(class cv::Mat &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &,double &)" (?detectAndDraw_image@MainWindow@@QEAA?AVMat@cv@@AEAV23@AEAU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@11AEAN@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> __cdecl cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier::create(class cv::String const &)" (?create@CascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VCascadeClassifier@cuda@cv@@@3@AEBVString@3@@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(void)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QEAA@XZ) в функции "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(void)" (??1VideoCapture@cv@@UEAA@XZ) в функции "public: virtual __cdecl MainWindow::~MainWindow(void)" (??1MainWindow@@UEAA@XZ)
debug\smile_detector.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 21
jom: C:\Qt\qt_projects\smile_detector\build-smile_detector-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\smile_detector.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Qt\qt_projects\smile_detector\build-smile_detector-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
07:05:26: Процесс «C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта smile_detector (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.10.1 MSVC2017 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
07:05:26: Прошло времени: 00:13.
```

Comment: А что это у вас библиотеки vc, а команды для сборки как для mingw / gcc?

Comment: @VTT, посмотрите, заменил тут win64, но все равно, не очень успешно все.